# Migrating from webpack 2.7 to 4.1.1, noticed bad performance results

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

I have a quite big vue js project and I am trying to migrate from webpack 2.7 to the last version 4.1.1.
I manage to have it working but the final bundle is bigger than before. And I don't understand why.

**BEFORE**

```
 app.bundle.js  2.72 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
```

**AFTER**

```
app.bundle.js  4.48 MiB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
```

This is my common config:

```
var LodashModuleReplacementPlugin = require('lodash-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

// Don't display loaders deprecation in the npm run console.
process.noDeprecation = true

function resolve(dir) {
  return path.resolve(__dirname, dir)
}

module.exports = {
  entry: ["babel-polyfill", './app/main.js'],
  output: {
    path: resolve('./app'),
    publicPath: '/app/',
    filename: 'app.bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.vue$/,
      loader: 'vue-loader',
      options: {
        loaders: {
          'scss': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader!sass-loader',
          'sass': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
        }
      }
    }, {
      test: /\.js$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      'query': {
        'plugins': ['lodash'],
        'presets': ['es2015']
      }
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader']
    }, {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader']
    },
    {
      test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
      loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000'
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js',
      'core': resolve('app/components/core/'),
      'common': resolve('app/components/common/'),
      'public': resolve('app/components/public/'),
      'private': resolve('app/components/private/'),
      styles: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app')
    },
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json', '.scss'],
    modules: [resolve('./app'), 'node_modules']
  },

  performance: {
    hints: false
  },

  plugins: [new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery",
    "window.jQuery": "jquery",
    Tether: "tether",
    "window.Tether": "tether",
    "_": 'lodash',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
    Alert: "exports-loader?Alert!bootstrap/js/dist/alert",
    Button: "exports-loader?Button!bootstrap/js/dist/button",
    Carousel: "exports-loader?Carousel!bootstrap/js/dist/carousel",
    Collapse: "exports-loader?Collapse!bootstrap/js/dist/collapse",
    Dropdown: "exports-loader?Dropdown!bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown",
    Modal: "exports-loader?Modal!bootstrap/js/dist/modal",
    Popover: "exports-loader?Popover!bootstrap/js/dist/popover",
    Scrollspy: "exports-loader?Scrollspy!bootstrap/js/dist/scrollspy",
    Tab: "exports-loader?Tab!bootstrap/js/dist/tab",
    Tooltip: "exports-loader?Tooltip!bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip",
    Util: "exports-loader?Util!bootstrap/js/dist/util",
  }), new LodashModuleReplacementPlugin({
    caching: true
  }), new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin,
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    MAX_UPLOAD_FILE_SIZE: 5242880,
    COPYRIGHT: "2018"
  })]
}
```

This is my prod config:

```
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
var webpack = require('webpack');

const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'production',
  devtool: '#source-map',
  plugins: [
    new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin(),
    new CompressionPlugin({
      asset: "[path].gz[query]",
      algorithm: "gzip",
      test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/,
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0
    }),
  ]
})
```

I also tried to add the optimization:

```
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        commons: {
          name: 'commons',
          chunks: 'all',
          minChunks: 2,
          enforce: true
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

but with same results...

What am I missing? thank you!

Comment: Have you tried looking at the bundles, eg.  does the new bundle have source-maps external / internal, or could it be the old bundle was uglified and the new one not. etc.. IOW: First step find out what's different in the bundles.

Comment: Good Idea, I will check right away. And by the way in webpack 4 it shouldn't uglify by default in production mode?

Comment: What it should do, and what's it doing might not be the same.  It might be an outdated changed configuration setting etc.  Are you using babel?, this can sometimes add a fair bit of code.

Comment: Hard to tell without `webpack.common.js`.

Comment: @BertrandMarron I've updated the question by adding the common as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking at development or production mode bundle sizes? In my experiences so far, the development mode build is larger in size, they aren't optimizing for size in dev, they are optimizing for compile/re-compile speed so I think they made a tradeoff here in v4 (my dev bundle builds about 1.7x faster).

If your production builds (with uglifyjs below) are bigger, then that is concerning.

Try adding uglifyjs to your production mode build:

`yarn add uglifyjs-webpack-plugin --dev`

```
const UglifyJsWebpackPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

config = {
  ...,
  optimization: {
    minimization: [
      new UglifyJsWebpackPlugin({
        parallel: true,
        sourceMap: <true/false>,
      })
    ],
  },
}
```